# FlexJS with Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flexjs

I want to try to use FlexJS with FlashBuilder

I https://cwiki.apache.org/FLEX/flexjs-status.html

And the page with the description how to set environmentreturn to me 404 error: https://cwiki.apache.org/FLEX/using-flexjs-with-adobe-flash-builder.html

Comment: Ask on the Apache Flex Dev list.  There was some conversation recently about problems with the Wiki. I'm not sure where the location is.   That said; I voted to close because your question is unspecific.  Are you asking where the proper link is?  OR some other type of help?

Comment: This question appear to be asking for the contents behind a link which no longer works as opposed to a specific programming problem. 

Comment: Is this the page you're after? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Using+FlexJS+with+Adobe+Flash+Builder

Answer (score 1):

This is the current page from the WIKI for using Flash Builder.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Using+FlexJS+with+Adobe+Flash+Builder

Also, Josh Tynjala has been working on some very nice tutorials and tools for FlexJS. He has a tutorials for the other IDE's. at [NextGenActionscript.com](http://nextgenactionscript.com)